# How do i make navbar background image scale to navbar border using css

Tags: css

The css i am using for the background image is shown below. My problem is that when the browser is resized the image doesnt resize to fill the navbar completely. See pictures below

```
#navmenu{
  width:auto;
  height:240px !important;

  background-image: url("../Images/IMG-20160222-WA0001.jpg");
  background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
  background-size:cover !important; /*strech to fit navbar border*/
}
```

I tried playing around with the width attribute and had no luck with this. Thanks.

[image: Cropped image view screen size decreased]
[image: Full image view when screen maximised]

**EDIT:**

With the option [`background-size:contain !important;`] the image does not fit the navbar border. please see last image.[image]

Comment: Maybe you want `background-size: contain` instead?

Comment: @Aides With the option [background-size:contain !important;] the image does not fit the navbar border. please see last image. Please see edit

Comment: The problem is that you can either fit your image along the shorter axis, along the longer axis or stretch it (what other result do you want to achieve?).

Comment: @Aides i want it to always be stretched, such that the full image is always fully displayed when the browser is resized. That is for picture 1, "LondolaGlass" should be fully displayed as shown in picture 2, regardless of the browser window size.

Comment: If you have a fixed height div this (technically and logically) won't be possible without stretching or cutting since the aspect ratio of the div changes (width is reduced, height is not) but the aspect ratio of the image stays the same.

Comment: The best option would then be using [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to create a responsive design and swap the image as soon as the width gets too low (for instance only the icon without the text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `background-size:contain`

```css
#navmenu {
  width: auto;
  height: 240px !important;
  background-image: url("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-size: contain !important;
  /*strech to fit navbar border*/
}
```

```html
<div id="navmenu">
</div>
```

Comment: With the option [background-size:contain !important;] the image does not fit the navbar border. please see last image. Please see edit